# Different notifications to different activities

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice

I have 2 types of custom notifications in my Android application:

1. Notify user about coming event (A)
2. Notify user when the timer is finished (B)

When user sees notification A and click on it, the ActivityA must be opened. The same story with notification B - ActivityB must be opened, ect.
I use one IntentService class to fire up all types of notifications.

**Question**: how to explain to Android which activity i want to open?

My only thought is to choose next activity by incoming values in intent parametr in `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)`. 
**Pseudocode:**

```
onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // some code
    if(intent.getInt(NOTIFICATION_TYPE) == 0) {
    // work with activity A
    }
    if(intent.getInt(NOTIFICATION_TYPE) == 1) {
    // work with activity B
    }
    if(intent.getInt(NOTIFICATION_TYPE) == 2) {
    // work with activity C
    }
    // and so on
}
```

Is there any better way to do it?
*(All notifications have title, content, date in Mills. Other params can vary)*

Comment: What is the problem with your current approach?

Comment: @Egor, i have not tested it yet. Just asking if there is any better solution?